# Memory leak due to IAddon class in HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, memory-leaks, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere, eclipse-memory-analyzer

It looks like I have a memory leak preventing my activities from being garbage collected. I did a memory dump and MAT shows that I have several instances of each activity. Consequently, my app crashes often due to memory leaks.

Under MAT, I can see that the reference retaining my activities is related to the IAddon class and the AddonSherlock class in the HoloEverywhere library. I do use HoloEverywhere and ActionBarSherlock in my application.

Here is a screen shot of the path to GC root (excluding weak references) for one of the retained activities (using MAT):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11061286/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-07%20at%202.55.37%20PM.png

Does anybody know what might be causing this leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like it was fixed in the latest version of HoloEverywhere. Here is the issue on Github if you want to know more: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/432